# CVCalendarKit - Ambiguous use of operator '=='

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Hi im using the CVcalendarKit Pod. Im trying to upgrade my Swift 2 code to Swift 3, but have som issues with the code. Im getting the "Ambiguous use of operator '=='. Anyone with a solution ?

```
public func == (lhs: Date, rhs: Date) -> Bool {
    return compareWithOperation({ $0 == $1 }, resultMerge: { $0 && $1 && $2 })(lhs, rhs)
}

public func >= (lhs: Date, rhs: Date) -> Bool {
    return compareWithOperation({ $0 > $1 || lhs == rhs }, resultMerge: { $0 || $1 || $2 })(lhs, rhs)
}

public func <= (lhs: Date, rhs: Date) -> Bool {
    return compareWithOperation({ $0 < $1 || lhs == rhs }, resultMerge: { $0 || $1 || $2 })(lhs, rhs)
}

public func != (lhs: Date, rhs: Date) -> Bool {
    return !(lhs == rhs)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Date` is already `Equatable` and `Comparable`. You cannot define new comparison operators because they are already defined in the standard library.

Don't use that Pod, it's dangerously outdated and a lot of the functionality is already included in the standard library (some of the functionality was in the standard library even when the pod was new).

Note that even the original functionality in `CVCalendarKit` was incorrect. For example, a `Date` represents a point in time while the library declared the comparison operator to only work on years, months and days (similar to library function `Calendar.compare(_:to:toGranularity:)`).

You don't need custom accessors in the form of:

```
let newDate = date.year + 1
```

when the standard library is already giving you:

```
let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: date)
```

Shorter does not mean better.

Nevertheless, the pod is no longer maintained and the functionality was moved to [CVCalendar](https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar), specifically the files [CVDate](https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar/blob/master/CVCalendar/CVDate.swift) and [CVCalendarManager](https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar/blob/master/CVCalendar/CVCalendarManager.swift) which are implemented a bit better than the original.

Comment: +1 just for the answer, +1000 if I could just for the final note. The more people try to simplify calendar calculations, the more they get the edge cases wrong (and there are always way more edge cases than one suspects). Time is wibbly wobbly stuff.